# T-SQL dynamically fill column with calculated data based on differences between row values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am struggling with the following issue (simplified form). I have a table with 53 rows and for column [No of Days] only some of the rows contain a quantity. In the column [Days Calculated] I want to dynamically calculate the Days for the rows that do not contain a quantity, adding the difference between 2 rows with a quantity evenly among the rows without quantity. If there is no difference than use the same quantity.

Rows without a quantity before the first row with a quantity should be filled with quantity of this row.
Rows without a quantity after the last row with a quantity should be filled with the quantity of this row.

The source I have are the first 2 columns, I need to add the 3rd column.

| Period No | No of Days | Days Calculated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | NULL | 77 |
| 2 | NULL | 77 |
| 3 | NULL | 77 |
| removed some rows | NULL | 77 |
| 22 | 77 | 77 |
| 23 | NULL | 75,83 |
| 24 | NULL | 74,66 |
| 25 | NULL | 73,49 |
| 26 | NULL | 72,32 |
| 27 | NULL | 71,15 |
| 28 | 70 | 70 |
| 29 | NULL | 70 |
| removed some rows | NULL | 70 |
| 45 | 70 | 70 |
| 46 | NULL | 73,50 |
| 47 | 77 | 77 |
| 48 | NULL | 77 |
| removed some rows | NULL | 77 |
| 53 | 77 | 77 |

I have tried to solve this with making a ranking and a case statement with the possible conditions but have not been able to completely get it right. I have the feeling there are better ways.

Any guidance in the right direction is much appreciated !

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired output and while doing that remember people prefer text over picture on Stack Overflow, Otherwise you may not get any answer and your question might be closed.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) If you want to provide sample data, DDL and DML is my far the best way. Otherwise you can use a markdown table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE testTable (PeriodNo INT, NoOfDaysPL MONEY);
INSERT INTO dbo.testTable(PeriodNo)
SELECT TOP(53)ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY t1.object_id) AS N
FROM sys.all_columns t1
     CROSS JOIN sys.all_columns AS t2;
UPDATE dbo.testTable SET NoOfDaysPL=77 WHERE PeriodNo=22;
UPDATE dbo.testTable SET NoOfDaysPL=70 WHERE PeriodNo=28;
UPDATE dbo.testTable SET NoOfDaysPL=70 WHERE PeriodNo=45;
UPDATE dbo.testTable SET NoOfDaysPL=77 WHERE PeriodNo=51;

SELECT PeriodNo, NoOfDaysPL, 
    CASE WHEN pv IS NULL THEN COALESCE(NoOfDaysPL, ndv)
         WHEN nv IS NULL THEN COALESCE(NoOfDaysPL, pdv)
         WHEN NoOfDaysPL IS NULL THEN pdv-((pdv-ndv)/(nv-pv)*(PeriodNo-pv))
         ELSE NoOfDaysPL 
    END NoOfDaysCalculated
FROM dbo.testTable AS tt
     CROSS APPLY(SELECT MAX(PeriodNo)
                 FROM dbo.testTable AS tt2
                 WHERE tt2.PeriodNo<tt.PeriodNo AND tt2.NoOfDaysPL IS NOT NULL) p(pv)
     CROSS APPLY(SELECT MIN(PeriodNo)
                 FROM dbo.testTable AS tt2
                 WHERE tt2.PeriodNo>tt.PeriodNo AND tt2.NoOfDaysPL IS NOT NULL) n(nv)
     OUTER APPLY(SELECT NoOfDaysPL FROM dbo.testTable AS tt2 WHERE tt2.PeriodNo=p.pv) pc(pdv)
     OUTER APPLY(SELECT NoOfDaysPL FROM dbo.testTable AS tt2 WHERE tt2.PeriodNo=n.nv) nc(ndv);
```

| PeriodNo | NoOfDaysPL | NoOfDaysCalculated |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | *null* | 77.0000 |
| 2 | *null* | 77.0000 |
| 3 | *null* | 77.0000 |
| 4 | *null* | 77.0000 |
| 5 | *null* | 77.0000 |
| 6 | *null* | 77.0000 |
| 7 | *null* | 77.0000 |
| 8 | *null* | 77.0000 |
| 9 | *null* | 77.0000 |
| 10 | *null* | 77.0000 |
| 11 | *null* | 77.0000 |
| 12 | *null* | 77.0000 |
| 13 | *null* | 77.0000 |
| 14 | *null* | 77.0000 |
| 15 | *null* | 77.0000 |
| 16 | *null* | 77.0000 |
| 17 | *null* | 77.0000 |
| 18 | *null* | 77.0000 |
| 19 | *null* | 77.0000 |
| 20 | *null* | 77.0000 |
| 21 | *null* | 77.0000 |
| 22 | 77.0000 | 77.0000 |
| 23 | *null* | 75.8334 |
| 24 | *null* | 74.6668 |
| 25 | *null* | 73.5002 |
| 26 | *null* | 72.3336 |
| 27 | *null* | 71.1670 |
| 28 | 70.0000 | 70.0000 |
| 29 | *null* | 70.0000 |
| 30 | *null* | 70.0000 |
| 31 | *null* | 70.0000 |
| 32 | *null* | 70.0000 |
| 33 | *null* | 70.0000 |
| 34 | *null* | 70.0000 |
| 35 | *null* | 70.0000 |
| 36 | *null* | 70.0000 |
| 37 | *null* | 70.0000 |
| 38 | *null* | 70.0000 |
| 39 | *null* | 70.0000 |
| 40 | *null* | 70.0000 |
| 41 | *null* | 70.0000 |
| 42 | *null* | 70.0000 |
| 43 | *null* | 70.0000 |
| 44 | *null* | 70.0000 |
| 45 | 70.0000 | 70.0000 |
| 46 | *null* | 71.1666 |
| 47 | *null* | 72.3332 |
| 48 | *null* | 73.4998 |
| 49 | *null* | 74.6664 |
| 50 | *null* | 75.8330 |
| 51 | 77.0000 | 77.0000 |
| 52 | *null* | 77.0000 |
| 53 | *null* | 77.0000 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/rkl1L0XM)